# Callback from PayPal. How to know the user paid successfully immediately?

Tags: php, web, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-ipn

I am running a e-commerce website and I want to integrate PayPal. I need to know immediately whether a user paid successfully or not after they paid via their credit cards. Is there a chance i can do that with PayPal?

I've heard PayPal has a service called IPN, which can post to my server and tell me the transaction's status. But lots of people are complaining that there are huge delays with IPN's PHP API.

Comment: @GBD can you go more details? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just finished an IPN integration a few hours ago :).

IPN stands for INSTANT payment notifications. In most times it just works(hi Apply fans!).

You add a form with variables such as currency and return URL and with a special page that you expect Paypal to send transaction information when the payment is made. Receiving a notification does not mean funds are sent to your account but the transaction has completed. (possible reasons to not get funds to your account include problems with card provider, incomplete accounts, etc)

You will face some questions regarding specific problems. But I would suggest checking paypal site and it's API docs. They are pretty straight forward and with a little understanding in your programming language and how HTTP works, you can implement it.

I have seen some posts about PayPal IPN system is slow. I have not seen it myself but in most cases, I'm sure you will get paypal API calls just before the user come back to your site.

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with [nSoftware's](http://www.nsoftware.com/download/php.aspx) PayPal plugins.